# I cant use my Windows 10 partition after reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

A while back, I posted about my GRUB rescue error and how i couldn't boot in either windows or ubuntu. So, after trying boot-repair and many other tools from my live USB, i decided to completely reinstall Ubuntu (16.04). I did so, and it worked; when i booted my computer i got the same purple grub screen telling me where i wanted to boot, i can choose Ubuntu and boot to Ubuntu. But here's the catch, before all this, in the purple screen, i could choose ubuntu or windows... Now i dont heve the option of booting to windows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you launch gparted and show us the result? Don't do anything there, just get a screenshot and upload it to here.

Comment: Yes, please do as @StarOS asked. I'm afraid you may have formatted your HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just learned the solution in an IRC chat.

I needed to go on launch the command `update-grub`. Then, whenever I reboot, I get to choose between Ubuntu and Windows